# What does the scope resolution operator return in case of Type::var?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, operators, member

Consider the following example:

```
class A { int x; };
```

Now what is `A::x`?

- It cannot be an lvalue because it does not refer to a storage Location.
- It cannot be a type, because the type would be `decltype(A::x)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is, in fact, an lvalue. [[expr.prim.id.qual]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.id.qual#2):

> A *nested-name-specifier* that denotes a class [...] followed by the
>   name of a member of either that class ([class.mem]) or one of its base
>   classes, is a *qualified-id* [...]. The result is the member. The type
>   of the result is the type of the member. The result is an lvalue if
>   the member is a static member function or a data member and a prvalue
>   otherwise.

Though its usage outside a class member access expression is severely restricted by [[expr.prim.id]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.id#2), it can notably be used in unevaluated operands, where its lvalueness can manifest:

```
struct A {
    int x;
};

void f(int &);

using p = decltype(&(A::x)); // p is int*; the parens prevents forming a pointer-to-member
using q = decltype(f(A::x)); // q is void
```

Comment: More interesting is why the parentheses prevent forming a pointer-to-member.

Comment: @DeiDei Because the rule is that a pointer to member is only formed by `& qualified-id`.

Answer (score 6):

`A::x` is merely a less ambiguous way of referring to the member `x` which can be necessary if the local context *shadows* that member:

---

Example 1:

A child class also has a member `x`.

```
struct B : public A
{
    int x;
    void foo()
    {
        int local_x = x;
        int parent_x = A::x;
    }
}
```

which would compile had you made `x` `protected` in class `A` (it's currently `private`).

---

Example 2:

You can even use it in a member *function* of `A` that has `x` as a parameter:

```
class A {
    int x;
    void foo(int x)
    {
        int parameter_x = x;
        int member_x = A::x;
    }
};
```

Comment: There's an implicit transformation to class member access expression here, though, so it isn't quite "what `::` returns".

Comment: @T.C. Yes I might have patronised the OP by misjudging the "level" of the question. Have an upvote on your answer to set it further ahead.

Comment: Or maybe I've gone too far on the language-lawyer side of things :) Hard to tell for sure what the OP is asking.

Comment: @T.C. You got me right. :) My question is not limited to situations that are related to shadowing.

Comment: @ManuelAtWork: Apologies for patronising you, although I did upvote your nicely written question.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Bathsheba's answer, which is correct when you're within the class's scope, `A::x` can also be used as part of a pointer-to-member expression, i.e. `&A::x`, which returns a `int A::*`.

In this case, the standalone `A::x` is not valid and therefore the question of what it returns is moot.

Comment: Feel free to nick my other points in order to make this more comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ Standard (5.1 Primary expressions)

> 9 A nested-name-specifier that denotes a class, optionally followed by
>   the keyword template (14.2), and then followed by the name of a member
>   of either that class (9.2) or one of its base classes (Clause 10), is
>   a qualified-id; 3.4.3.1 describes name lookup for class members that
>   appear in qualified-ids. The result is the member. The type of the
>   result is the type of the member. **The result is an lvalue if the
>   member is a static member function or a data member** and a prvalue
>   otherwise. [ Note: a class member can be referred to using a
>   qualified-id at any point in its potential scope (3.3.7). —end note
>   ]...

The qualified name allows to specify an otherwise hidden name for example when  derived and base classes have members with the same name. For example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int i;
};

struct B : A
{
    B( int i ) : A { i }, i( 2 * A::i ) {}
    int i;
    std::ostream &out( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
    {
        return os << "A::i = " << A::i << ", B::i = " << B::i;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B( 10 ).out() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A::i = 10, B::i = 20
```

Also (5.1 Primary expressions)

> 13 An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or
>   non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> (13.1) — as part of a class member access (5.2.5) in which the object
>   expression refers to the member’s class63 or a class derived from that
>   class, or
>
> (13.2) — to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), or
>
> (13.3) — if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it
>   appears in an unevaluated operand.

Answer (score -3):

`A::x` is exact equivalent of accessing static variable in JAVA.

Regarding your example:-

1) **x** will be variable for distinct objects

2) **A::x** will be the variable for the class itself. Regardless of how many objects of A has been declared for every object the value of `A::x` will be same until assignment.

For example:-

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A { 
public:
   static int x; 
};

int A::x;

int main()
{
   A a,b;

   a.x=8;

   b.x=6;

   A::x=10;


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is about a static member variable. But what does ```A::x``` mean for non-static member variables?